# How to make a search box not scrolling over scrollview Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-scrollview

*In my home screen I want to add the search box with navigation drawer but I am not able to set the non scrollable edittext over scrollview.*

**Here is my Code**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#ecedf1">






    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp" />



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
           >
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_280sdp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:text="fdgsdfhsfhsfghhsfhsfhf"
                android:background="@drawable/customedittext"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_180sdp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.information.aanjana.aanjanainformation.NonScrollGridView
            android:id="@+id/gv_android"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_299sdp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_220sdp"
            android:verticalSpacing="8dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_170sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want a edittext with navigation drawer which should be sticky and do not scroll with rest of the layout. How can I achive it.

***What I want is explained in screenshot below:***

[image]

Comment: Hi your UI looks cool :)

Comment: @GKTHEBOSS thanks but can you help me ? :)

Comment: can you tell me the `id` of your searchView which you want to keep out side the scroll part?

Comment: @himanshu1496 I havent given id to it but check edittext with this parameter **android:text="fdgsdfhsfhsfghhsfhsfhf"**

Comment: okay got it. will post my answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my below code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="#ecedf1">





<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">


        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_180sdp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <com.information.aanjana.aanjanainformation.NonScrollGridView
                android:id="@+id/gv_android"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_299sdp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_220sdp"
                android:verticalSpacing="8dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_280sdp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:text="fdgsdfhsfhsfghhsfhsfhf"
            android:background="@drawable/customedittext"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>




<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_170sdp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here Only thing which I have changed is kept the `editText` outside the `scrollView`.

Comment: that worked perfectly fine..but can you tell how can i set navigation drawer on serach box ?

Comment: One way of doing that is having a `button` on left side of  `search edit text` and set a `click listener` on that `button`, just open and close the `drawer` whenever it is clicked. But that's another question, please accept the answer if it worked to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to put it out outside the ScrollView. Then just overlay it with a RelativeLayout and the gravity set to `top`. I can't run it now but in xml should look like something like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="#ecedf1">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_180sdp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.information.aanjana.aanjanainformation.NonScrollGridView
        android:id="@+id/gv_android"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_299sdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_220sdp"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

<!-- Here we add the layout outside the ScrollView -->

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:gravity="top"> <!-- GRAVITY ADJUST -->

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_280sdp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:text="fdgsdfhsfhsfghhsfhsfhf"
            android:background="@drawable/customedittext"/>
    </RelativeLayout>



<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_170sdp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Hopefully, it runs smoothly and turns out helpful.

Comment: not working relative layout goes behind scrollview content

Comment: Just lay down first the scroll view and then the edittext layout. Edited it.

Comment: can you tell me how to set navigation drawer on search box like the image above I added ??